# Laravel 5.8 Custom Validator resolver not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I trying to migrate to Laravel 5.8 from my Laravel 5.6 though there's seem to be an error specifically to my Appservice as i'm injecting a CustomValidator class,

Here's my **CustomValidator.php** class

```
   namespace App\Laravel\Services;

    use App\Laravel\Models\User as Account;
    use Illuminate\Validation\Validator;
    use Auth, Hash,Str,Input;

    class CustomValidator extends Validator {

        public function validateUniqueUsername($attribute,$value,$parameters){
            $account_id = (is_array($parameters) AND isset($parameters[0]) ) ? $parameters[0] : "";
            $username = Str::lower($value);
            $is_exist = Account::whereRaw("LOWER(username) = '{$username}'")
                                ->first();
            return $is_exist ? FALSE: TRUE;
        }
   }
```

Then here's my **AppServiceProvider.php**

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use App\Laravel\Services\CustomValidator;
use Validator;


class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {

        Validator::resolver(function($translator, $data, $rules, $messages)
        {
            return new CustomValidator($translator, $data, $rules, $messages);
        });
    }
```

Please consider in my customvalidator i have a lot of custom validator created to my own platform.

I'm receiving this kind of error.

[image]

Comment: either way there's no luck this settings works in my laravel 5.6 we've been using this configuration since laravel 5.2

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for `Validator::extend` instead as described [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#using-extensions).

Comment: We have more than 10 custom validator . we can't do something like this in the AppServiceProvider file. we need to store in somewhere as a class.